# $1$-$1$ holomorphic function on a simple closed contour is $1$-$1$ inside the contour?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f(z)$ is holomorphic inside and on a simple closed contour $C.$

I'd like to prove the following:

**If $f(z)$ is a one-to-one function on $C$, then $f(z)$ is one-to-one function inside $C.$**

I don't know how to prove it. The only thing I know is that $f(C)$ is a simple closed contour, since $f$ is one-to-one on a simple closed contour $C$.

Please let me know if you have any idea or comment for this question.

Thanks in advance!